# List google spreadsheets created with gspread

Tags: python, gspread

I used gspread to create some spreadsheet.

As they are created with a google services key account, I don't know how can I access them.

How can I see all the spreadsheets created with a specific service key?

https://github.com/burnash/gspread

Comment: You can use `openall()` for this: http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gspread.Client.openall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

After looking directly in the gspread code, I found this : https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/addd4940bf7e4f87aae598920facae2155e555b6/gspread/client.py#L151

So this works :

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gspread
from gspread.ns import _ns

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """

    return ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)

credentials = get_credentials()
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
feed = gc.get_spreadsheets_feed()

for elem in feed.findall(_ns('entry')):
    elem_title = elem.find(_ns('title')).text
    print(elem_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried list comprehension, but it still did not solve the problem. I passed this as the second parameter to the connection.

```
alltogether= ','.join([str(item) for item in gendata])
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35359830)